# Using preg_replace to wrap highlighted text by mouse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, preg-replace

Is there a way to use these buttons that spit out a specific text, but put them around (wrap) the highlighted text *(by mouse)*?

I have no idea how to do that and Google wasn't helping either. I am using `Wordpress` by the way.

```
$(".ztn").on("click", function () {
    var setText = $("#commentext").val()+" (zie: )";
    $("#commentext").val(setText);
});
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var setText = $("#commentext").val()+" ` `";
    $("#commentext").val(setText);
});
```

And this my code in `functions.php:`

```
function replace_content($content)
{
$content = preg_replace('#\(check: (.*?)\)#', "(check: <a class='zak' href='".site_url()."/$1/'>$1</a>)", $content);
preg_match("#class='zak' href='(.*?)'#", $content, $link);
if(count($link)>0){
$link = $link[1];
$link = preg_replace("# #", "-", $link);
$content = preg_replace("#class='zak' href='(.*?)'#", "class='zak' href='".$link."'", $content);
}
$content = preg_replace('#`(.*?)`#', "<a class='zbk' href='".site_url()."/$1/'>$1</a>", $content);
preg_match("#class='zbk' href='(.*?)'#", $content, $link1);
if(count($link1)>0){
$link1 = $link1[1];
$link1 = preg_replace("# #", "-", $link1);
$content = preg_replace("#class='zbk' href='(.*?)'#", "class='zbk' href='".$link1."'", $content);
}
return $content;
}
```

And:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-defaul ztn">button 1</button><button type="button" class="btn-default btn">button 2</button></div>
```

Now, when I highlight a text by my mouse and click on this button, it is not being wrapped. The text that is being outputted after clicking the button, is just placed on top of the input field, while I want it to wrap the highlighted text.

Comment: How are you interfacing JS and PHP?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, VLAZ? You want to see the HTML snippet?

Comment: If you're doing things on the client in response to client activity you're probably better doing everything in JavaScript.

Comment: You have PHP code and you have JavaScript code but no apparent link between them when there should be. In the code you've shown nothing ever calls `replace_conent` and the result of that is never passed around to JS.

Comment: Ah. I have added my buttons where the JS is triggered. @VLAZ

Comment: @Siyah OK, but how are you invoking the PHP function?

Comment: You mean the filters? add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
add_filter('get_comment_text','replace_content');

Comment: Can We see a demo elsewhere (perhaps some other webpage) of what are you trying to achieve?